# Stop wordpress auto redirect /admin to /wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

Word press is automatically redirecting my /admin to /wp-admin. Is there a way i can stop this?

I have a separate admin area i can no longer access.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
add_action(
  'template_redirect', 
  function() {
    $requ = untrailingslashit($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (site_url('admin','relative') === untrailingslashit( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )){
      remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000 );
    }
  }
);
```

Removes Wordpress's hook to do the redirect.